# How to test the SSIS Packages?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, ssis, automated-tests, integration-testing

How to test the SSIS Packages ?

what are the things should be taken care while testing
the ssis packages?

what are the testcase steps should be written while testing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ssisUnit](http://ssisunit.codeplex.com/) is a great tool for unit testing an SSIS package.  The only caveat I have run into is that you need to run the unit tests on a machine with SSIS server components installed.  I work in a shop where I have the SSIS client components installed, but the server is remote (I have Sql Server Express on my local box) so I am currently unable to use ssisUnit in my development.  This means I have to write my scripts manually which is a much bigger pain.